# USB Device With Embedded Fileserver

Tags: file-sharing, ethernet, usb

I'm attempting to access logs from a proprietary hardware box with no reasonable hope of modifying the software. There is a process on the device to dump log files to a flash drive on the USB port after entering a code sequence.

Currently, analysis of the logs requires the following:

1. Physical presence at the device
2. Manual entry of the code sequence
3. Removal of USB device
4. Insertion of USB device into a normal Linux box

I'm hoping there is some sort of device that can act as a USB mass storage device but simultaneously make it's contents available as a network file share (wired preferred).

Does such a device currently exist? A combo hardware/software solution would also work.

Comment: Like an Android phone?

Comment: Newer android phones no longer are usb storage devices, prefering MTP instead.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a simple USB switch for this (for example [this](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Belkin-USB-Peripheral-Auto-Switch/dp/B0002AG9Z8) device)?

You would need to wire the USB switch to both your log analysis workstation and your log producing device with USB cables.  Then when you need to dump the logs, you would configure the switch to attach the USB drive to your log producing device and dump the logs.  Afterwards, you reattach the device to your log analysis workstation and copy/analyse the logs.

Some of these switches allow network access, so you may even be able to have a remote log analysis machine and partially script the whole process.

-- ab1